# Facebook Login For Rest Api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook login SPA. I am using the JavaScript SDK for the login. Fb authorized the user and token is received. Token is send to the web API. When API try to fetch the data from the token only Facebook id and name return from the Facebook graph api. Even though I have set the scope for the different data in java script sdk. If i fetch the data using javascript sdk. In that case i am getting the complete data whatever in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking "why am I not getting all the data I requested?". If so the most common reason is because permissions aren't set. For instance if the user grants permission to `"public_profile"` then Facebook will authorize your app to obtain every field that that the `"public_profile"` permission permits, in this case the following:

```
id, name, first_name, last_name, age_range, link, gender, locale, picture, timezone, updated_time, verified
```

obtained via

```
  FB.api('/me',  
         'GET', 
          {"fields":"id,name"},  //any of the other fields here
          function(response) {
           // Insert your code here  
           } );
```

however if added '`email`' in as a field then the Facebook would return everything except the '`email`' because there a permission specifically for granting access to the users email called `email`. You can see what permissions enable what data returns at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
and you can test it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. I hope that's what you where trying to say in your question. Cheers!